# When is the supremum of a vector field finite?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, vector-fields, lipschitz-functions

Let $v(t,x(t))$ be a velocity vector field and $[0,T]$ an interval. My question would be the following: If I want
$$ L:=\sup_{t\in[0,T], x\in \mathbb{R}} \mid v'(t,x(t))\mid$$
to be finite, i.e. $L<\infty$, what conditions would I need to have for $v(t,x(t))$?

Would it be enough to assume that $v(t,x(t))$ is Lipschitz continuous? Because that would mean I have an $K\geq 0$ with
$$\mid v(t,x)-v(t,x(t))\mid \leq K\mid x-x(t)\mid, $$
and therefore have an upper bound for the derivative
$$v'(t,x(t))\leq K .$$
How would I show that $L$ is finite?

Comment: Can you please clarify: 1. What $v'$ means given that $v$ is a function of two variables; 2. What control you have over $x$ (continuity? differentiability? continuous differentiability? solution of some ODE related to $v$...?)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Of course! So, $x(t)$ describes the path of a particle in 2-dim space and therefore $x'(x)=v(t,x(t))$. $v'$ is the derivative of $v$ with respect to the time $t$.  Since I just need to assure that $L$ is finite, I can decide which assumptions I need for x...